# How to setup Frank Automation on real device?

Tags: ios, testing, automation, cucumber, frank

I have tried frank on iOS simulator. But need to know, how to run the tests on real device i.e on iPhone ? How will be the connection between device and Mac? through WIFI ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same thig right now.  [This tutorial](http://testingwithfrank.com/device.html) is listed on Frank's site, but I've been having problems with it, as I haven't had a lot of experience with terminal.  You probably have already found out something on it, but this might help someone else.